# proxy in java only showing 1 server reply

Tags: java, proxy

I have posted my java proxy code below.

It works but it only gives me 1 server response instead of everything.

After the 1 response I just get client sent packets but with a size of 0.

Screenshots also attached.

Any ideas?

I've done some debugging. If I remove everything in between

```
typ = streamFromServer.readUnsignedShort();

siz = streamFromServer.readUnsignedShort();
siz <<= 8;
siz |= streamFromServer.readUnsignedByte();

byte[] dat = new byte[siz];

streamFromServer.readFully(dat, 0, siz);

String FullHe = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(dat);

System.out.println("Server sending data to Client:");
System.out.println("Type:           " + typ + "");
System.out.println("Data Size:      " + siz + "");
System.out.println("Full Data:      " + FullHe + "");
System.out.println("\n\n");
```

Which is from the reading server response code it works and I get the client packets. How come it doesn't work with server packets?

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.net.*;

public class proxy{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("log.txt"));
    //System.setOut(out);

        try{
            String host = "gamea.clashofclans.com";
            int remoteport = 9339;
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9339);
            int localport = ss.getLocalPort();
            ss.setReuseAddress(true);
            // Print a start-up message
            System.out.println("Starting proxy for " + host + ":" + remoteport
              + " on port " + localport);
            // And start running the server
            runServer(host, remoteport, localport,ss); // never returns
            System.out.println("Started proxy!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to start proxy" +e+ "");
        }

    }

    public static void runServer(String host, int remoteport, int localport, ServerSocket ss)
    throws IOException {

    final byte[] request = new byte[2048];
    byte[] reply = new byte[4096];

        while (true) {
            Socket client = null, server = null;
            try {

                System.out.println("Waiting for Client");
                client = ss.accept();
                System.out.println("Client Accepted!");

                DataInputStream streamFromClient = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream streamToClient = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

                System.out.println("Connecting to server...");

                // Make a connection to the real server.
                server = new Socket("gamea.clashofclans.com", 9339);
                System.out.println("Just connected client to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());


                DataInputStream streamFromServer = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream streamToServer = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

                 Thread t = new Thread() {
                  public void run() {
                    int bytesRead;
                    int type;
                    int size;
                    int version;
                    try {
                      while ((bytesRead = streamFromClient.read(request)) != -1) {

                        type = streamFromClient.readUnsignedShort();

                        size = streamFromClient.readUnsignedShort();
                        size <<= 8;
                        size |= streamFromClient.readUnsignedByte();

                        version = streamFromClient.readUnsignedByte();

                        byte[] data = new byte[size];

                        streamFromClient.readFully(data, 0, size);

                        String FullHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data);

                        System.out.println("Client sending data to server:");
                        System.out.println("Type:           " + type + "");
                        System.out.println("Data Size:      " + size + "");
                        System.out.println("Version:        " + version + "");
                        System.out.println("Full Data:      " + FullHex + "");
                        System.out.println("\n\n");

                        streamToServer.write(request, 0, bytesRead);
                        streamToServer.flush();
                      }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }

                    // the client closed the connection to us, so close our
                    // connection to the server.
                    try {
                      streamToServer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }

                  }
                };

                t.start();

                int bytesRea;
                int typ;
                int siz;
                try {

                    while ((bytesRea = streamFromServer.read(reply)) != -1) {

                        typ = streamFromServer.readUnsignedShort();

                        siz = streamFromServer.readUnsignedShort();
                        siz <<= 8;
                        siz |= streamFromServer.readUnsignedByte();

                        byte[] dat = new byte[siz];

                        streamFromServer.readFully(dat, 0, siz);

                        String FullHe = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(dat);

                        System.out.println("Server sending data to Client:");
                        System.out.println("Type:           " + typ + "");
                        System.out.println("Data Size:      " + siz + "");
                        System.out.println("Full Data:      " + FullHe + "");
                        System.out.println("\n\n");

                        streamToClient.write(reply, 0, bytesRea);
                        streamToClient.flush();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                }



        } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
              } finally {
                try {
                  if (server != null)
                    server.close();
                  if (client != null)
                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
              }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could people please stop voting to close this question. Nothing unclear about it IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make sense. You're reading up to 4096 bytes from the server and *then* reading two type bytes and three length bytes and what you think is the request data, and writing what you read originally. So you're consuming the data about twice.

This can't work. You need to *either* just read the type, length, and value, *and write them out again,* or else, much more simply, just copy bytes from the input to the output, in both directions. (That way of course you can't do logging.)

NB Don't ignore `IOExceptions`, and especially not `EOFExceptions` when reading from `DataInputStreams` (or `ObjectInputStreams`).

Comment: I read from the fixed byte sizes first so I can get the size of the packet from the headers. How do I solve the current problem though?

Comment: Again, that doesn't make sense. You don't need to read bytes when you are *also* reading the type, length, and value, and you can't, because when you are reading the raw bytes you are *skipping over* the type/length/value, in some entirely unpredictable way, so that almost certainly when you do read the type/length/value, you are out of sync with the input. I suggest you *try* it without the raw read: in which case the exit from the loop occurs when you catch `EOFException`.

Comment: Aha ok, I've done it in multiple files:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27938441?noredirect=1 Thanks!

Comment: @Shiv The relevance of that link escapes me.

Comment: It's a seperate question. I was wondering if you knew how to seeing as you are epic in Java.

Comment: You were wondering if I knew how to what? And if you can't compile it, how come you know how it behaves at runtime?

Comment: The code here did compile but only gave 1 server reply. The code on that link is on multiple files and I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: So you're now asking a different question from the one I have answered here, and that you have already asked elewhere?

Comment: I'm just askiyou to check out my other question out... I used what you said and just put them in seperate files..

Comment: @Shiv I have zero interest in your difficulties with putting class files into separate files. That's Java 101 and you should be able to solve it on your own.

Comment: Ok then. What about the problem where I'm unable to get the entire packet written.

Comment: You need to write out the type and length in the same format you read them in, before writing the data. In other words you have to come up with the inverse of the four lines that read them. Leaving this as an exercise for the reader.